# Web Protect ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-6

Is there a way to web protect ASP.NET website so it asks user for username/password to view?

I've been told that this should go in web.config file, but not sure of how to do this, or what should go in there. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an intranet scenario it's quite simple. Add this in your web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authentication mode=”Windows”  />
 <authorization>
 <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Fastest way for internet applications:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
   <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx"> 
    <credentials> 
     <user name="user" password="password" /> 
     <user name="user2" password="password2" /> 
    </credentials> 
   </forms> 
  </authentication> 

  <authorization> 
    <deny users="?"/> 
  </authorization>
```

You will also need a new page login.aspx with a form where the user can enter his credentials. On the code behind page you then need the following code:

```
string username = textBoxUsername.Text; 
string password = textBoxPassword.Text; 

if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password)) 
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
```

Comment: Hi, its not an intranet and the website is hosted on a microsoft web server and as such we need to issue a username/password for people to login with as at the moment the whole world can view it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that and I can simply add that to the web.config file and all will be fine for what I need, less the need to do anything else?

Comment: You also need a page for the user to enter credentials, I updated my post to show the code needed.

Comment: Thanks and this will web protect the entire domain?

Comment: This will protect the pages in your asp.net web application. If you have files not belonging to the application, they will not be protected.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is setup **Web Authentication** on IIS. Check these links:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a296d63d-6fc5-47c5-b1fd-0aa0e1e18660.mspx?mfr=true

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324274

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308160

http://www.authenticationtutorial.com/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

[You should read the Form authentication in this sample article here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/08/forms-authentication-in-aspnet.html)